# Adding style to a div created in javascript

Tags: javascript

Quick question, I've got a div being created in javascript:

```
var chartDiv = document.createElement("div");
this.viewElement.appendChild(chartDiv);
```

But I want to set a border style around this div after its created. Whats the best way to do this in the javascript? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the element style object.

```
chartDiv.style.border = "thin solid #FFF";
```

Alternatively, just add a css class to your element that contains the styling you want.

Answer (score 1):

Create a style you'd like your `DIV` to have:

```
div.bordered {
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

And then add the class to your `DIV`:

```
var chartDiv = document.createElement('div');
chartDiv.className = 'bordered';
this.viewElement.appendChild(chartDiv);
```

This will allow you to style your `DIV` better, and add more than just the border.

Comment: Yep thats a good answer, but the nature of it is to only be rendered in javascript, otherwise I would have leaned more on CSS. Jecoms provided me the answer though, but I appreciate the help anyway